# Splicing a list at different intervals based on a value of a list in python

Tags: python, list, for-loop

Instead of posting a long winded example, I will post a simplified idea of what I want to achieve.

This is a bit of code that doesn't work, but it is what I want to do. I would like to take the last 4 values of list1 and append them to a new list, then take the last 3 values and append them to the same list and then take the last 2 values and append them to that same list.

Basically `print list2` would give `[[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4],[3,4]]`

Here is the code;

```
def test():
    list1 = range(5)
    list2 = []
    q=[2,4,6]
    j=0
    for j in range(len(q)):
        list2.append(list1[(q[j]*0.5):])
    print list2
```

Thank you

Comment: What is the purpose of `q=[2,4,6]` here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following code snippet

```
list2 = [list1[-i:] for i in range(4,1,-1)]
```

For example

```
>>> list1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> list2 = [list1[-i:] for i in range(4,1,-1)]    
>>> list2
[[6, 7, 8, 9], [7, 8, 9], [8, 9]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code does something different, but after your description, this should do it:

```
for l in range(len(list1), 0, -1):
   list2.append(list1[-l:])
```